# Scrapy does not fetch all the content

Tags: scrapy

I have to fetch customer reviews from [here](https://www.merchology.com/collections/mens-softshell-jackets/products/z500-zusa-black-cross-hatch-jacket). I know I can do it with Scrapy, but I do not have any considerable experience with crawling, and I have not used it. So, I am newly learning Scrapy.

I run Scrapy on shell. Although I can access **"<div>"**, I can not fetch the review text content.

Could you spare some help for me?

Thanks,

Comment: The product reviews are generated with javascript so you'll need to find another way.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the network tab you will notice that the reviews are obtained from this api endpoint ([https://cdn-ws.turnto.com/v5/sitedata/2VYPxicQbNXr64msite/1985142227034/d/review/en_US/0/10/{}/RECENT/false/true/?](https://cdn-ws.turnto.com/v5/sitedata/2VYPxicQbNXr64msite/1985142227034/d/review/en_US/0/10/%7B%7D/RECENT/false/true/?)) which returns json response that you can parse to obtain the required information.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have the sitemap information of the whole website, and I can fetch all the product pages. Could you kindly also show me an example python script that will automate finding this information? Then I can apply it to the whole website? Thanks